# How to traverse and click on Next & Cancel Button (On PopUp) using selenium webdriver

Tags: css, selenium, webdriver, selector, popupwindow

I have a pop up window on webpage where in I need to click on "Next" and "Cancel" button. I have tried navigating and find the CSS selector but couldn't able to locate and click on Next & Cancel button.
Below is the Fire bug things when I got after hovering on Next & Cancel Button.

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all
         ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria- 
         disabled="false">
             <span class="ui-button-text">Next</span>
        </button>
        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
        </button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to use : `type="submit"`  and `type="reset"`  instead `type="button"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search by `xpath` and the button text

```
// click on next button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Next')]")).click();

// click on cancel button    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]")).click();
```

Or using `cssSelector`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-button-text:contains('Next')")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-button-text:contains('Cancel')")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Guy.It worked with xpath but didnt work with cssSelector. And also Thank you others who took time to lend there idea thoughts for me.

Comment: @user3349459 You are welcome. I don't really know any site for this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if it is a popup, there are three types: alert, confirm and prompt. I will give you the solution for the alert which should work with confirm as well and try it. Please let me know if it works and I can help you if I have more info. I am using C#. Use the "SwitchTo() method of IWebDriver interface and Alert() method of the IAlert interface (this has got Accept and Dismiss methods which are your OK/Cancel on the popup).

Code: (assuming the action that fires the popup has been performed)

```
 IAlert alert = Driver.SwitchTo().Alert();   
  alert.Accept();
 //or alert.Dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case clicking on the span (as per @Guy's answer) doesn't work, try -

```
// click on next button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(., 'Next')]")).click();

// click on cancel button    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(., 'Cancel')]")).click();
```